# Selectable (flat) columns from tree structure

Tags: lists, data-tree

I have source fields in tree structure and target fields in list structure (target is for grid columns).

Now when I move parent node to right, what should be ideal way to handle it? should that be disabled and allow child node to be moved?

Any better suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Now when I move parent node to right, what should be the ideal way to handle it? should that be disabled and allow the child node to be moved? -- On this slightly difficult to answer. What's the functional requirement? Why are you thinking to disable it?

Comment: as that item is already selected. i thought to disable it. so that people dont try to move them again. I googled some other example and found one solution. I removed move buttons. and whatever is checked will be added to right. and on uncheck they will be removed from right. so that way problem has been solved.